# Symfony form do not submit data - POST request is empty

Tags: php, forms, twig, symfony4

I am new to symfony and twig templates and I am struggling with a problem of submiting data using form created by formbuilder in Symfony. Clicking "create" button does not submit data. I created a template addEmployee.html.twig which is extending base template with navbar and sidebar.

**I noticed that this form works only if I am not extending base.** So it will create proper request and submit the form only if the template in which the form is created doesnt have any parent template.

I dont know why extending base.html.twig template causing loosing of the request and I have no idea how to get it work with extending templates I have already builded.

newEmployee Function from MainController.php

```php
  /**
     * @Route("/employee/add", name="add_employee")
     * @Method({"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function newEmployee(Request $request){


      $employee = new Employee();

      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($employee)
          ->setMethod('POST')
          ->add('employeeNumber',TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class'=>'form-control')))
          ->add('name',TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class'=>'form-control')))
          ->add('phone',TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class'=>'form-control')))
          ->add('pool',TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class'=>'form-control')))
          ->add('save',SubmitType::class, array('label'=>'Create','attr'=>array('class'=> 'btn btn-primary mt-3')))
          ->getForm();

          if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
          }


      if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){

          $employee=$form->getData();

          $entityManager= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $entityManager->persist($employee);
          $entityManager->flush();

          return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
      }

          return $this->render('/Employee/addEmployee.html.twig',array('form'=>$form->createView()));

  }
```

addEmployee.html.twig'

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title%} New Article{% endblock %}

{% block body%}

{{form_start(form)}}
{{form_widget(form)}}
{{form_end(form)}}

{% endblock %}
```

base.html.twig

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}TL Manage{% endblock %}</title>        
        {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>

    {% include 'inc/navbar.html.twig' %}
    {% include  'inc/sidebar.html.twig' %}
     <div id="content">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
     </div>

    {% block javascript %}
    <!-- Icons.JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.5/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Popper.JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Custom Scroller CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
     {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of redirecting to homepage and inserting data 
[this is what happenes if I submit the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkC3K.png)

and after removing `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}` from addEmployee.html.twig' form works as intended. Any ideas how to get it work with the rest of the ui parts?

Comment: Are you look your profiler ?

Comment: How do you know the form is not submitted? Have you tried dumping the `$request` variable, or the `$form` inside the `$form->isSubmitted()` block?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried to separate condition $form->isSubmitted and after submit it always return false.  

And I have checked profiler - it shows no parameters on post request only get parameters i.e.  
[▼
  "plp" => "123456"
  "name" => "John"
  "phone" => "123 123 123 "
  "pool" => "shared"
  "save" => ""
]

But to be honest I dont know what should I check more in the profiler

Comment: First you must check the request to ensure you have something, certainly missconfigured but at least something sumbitted. so a little `dump($request->request)` you should find value of `name` and others. Then to handle a request just use `$form->handleRequest($request)` symfony will do the map alone. If it works without your extends is certainly because your js change your DOM. I don't see another possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a cause and solution by myself and I feel embarassed...

It turns out I had another form  in sidebar which was included in base template and I did not close `<form>` tag... so it was like this:

inc/sidebar.html.twig

```html
 <form class="employee-Finder">
       <input class="finder-input" type="text">
 <form> <!-- this was the cause -->
```

So the submit button from the first form was probably submitting the one in the sidebar which by default has get method. After closing the tag all works fine. Thank You for all your suggestions.